# python win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout(), doesnt change language in IDLE shell?

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard, python-idle

Can someone help me out please...I'm trying to start my first programming project. It will be implemented in python.

I need to have a textbox (which i am using  wxpython for). If the user enters any text into this text box, then I want it to appear as arabic. I wanted to this by automagically changing the users Keyboard to an arabic layout when the cursor lands in the given text box.

So i found this pywin32 module, which has a function LoadKeyboardLayout()
So i am trying to test this in IDLE, to see if I can make it accept arabic text into IDLE, to see if it works. So I enter, into IDLE:

```
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000401',1)
```

This then returns, 67175425, the decimal equivalent of hex:'4010401' whcih I believe is the locale ID for Arabic. SO I think wow! I've done it, but when I try typing after this, in the IDLE window, it continues to type normal english characters.

Can someone please explain my errors and guide me towards a good solution.

---

## **UPDATE**

Okay, I've been trying to solve this problem ever since posting the damn question.
No luck.
Then, I thought, "ok, screw it, instead of testing it quicly in IDLE, I will just try it out, in situ, in my source code for the project."
WTF - it worked first time, giving exact behaviour that I wanted.
Then I tried it in a different IDE, in the interpreted window, and again, IT WORKED straight away!

So clearly my issue is with IDLE, in its interpreting mode.
Can anyone explain why it doesn't work in the IDLE shell???

Comment: this sounds like a very odd  thing to do. How can you type arabic on an english keyboard for example?

Comment: either phonetically e.g. 's' has same sound as 'س' so the 's' key can be used for that. and so on for similar sounding letters.

or by just making it like windows makes their arabic layout, if you choose arabic as an input language. in which case seemingly random keys are assigned to the various arabic letters. I think u can buy keyboard overlay stickers which help identify which keys work for whcih arabic letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Keyboard layout setting in Windows is per-process (and inherited from the parent process)
2. IDLE runs your Python script in a background process separate from its GUI

So you have successfully changed the keyboard layout of the background Python process that is running your script, but not of IDLE's GUI.

Comment: Thanks for making sense of that for me. If I was registered I would upvote you or something.